# When should you use absolute pathnames when creating a symbolic link?

Tags: linux, symlink

I have read here and in few books that making symbolic links using relative pathway is preferred because if you move link and file, it won't break. I wondering if we should always create relative pathway symbolic links? Like for example if I want to link `/etc/passwd` to current directory, should I use absolute or relative path?

`ln -rs /etc/passwd passwd-symlink` will create the relative pathway link but is this necessary?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You do what you need - these things have different use cases. If you want a link to be relative, you use a relative link; if you need it to be absolute, you use an absolute link.

Comment: For example, you have a link "configs-enabled/config.txt" that points to another file that's always in "../configs-available/`; in this case, you want a relative link. You have config file that should always point to /etc/config.txt? Then you clearly want an absolute path. This becomes more clear when you realize that not all processes necessarily see the same file system hierarchy (e.g. due to Linux namespaces/containers, or chroot, or due to bind mounts, or due to the same volume being mounted at a different place on a different machine), so /etc/config.txt might be different!

Comment: @MarcusMüller The question is under what scenarios would you use a relative vs. absolute pathway. I am asking for a decision process of using one over other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably not one clear answer for this, and there are many instances where it doesn't particularly matter if a symlink target is relative or absolute.

It is probably a good idea to use a relative symlink if any of the following apply, because the link will remain valid in these situations:

- if the target is in the same directory tree and the whole tree could be moved
- If the target is in the same filesystem, and it gets mounted somewhere else in some future mount (perhaps in a rescue live environment or a container or on another system)

However an absolute link might be better if any of the following apply

- the target is in a radically different directory, where the right number of `../` sequences might not be clear
- you want to point to a very specific file that is not relative to the current directory (for example, a config file in /etc maybe)
- if you want to be very clear what file this points to, when a realtive link might turn into a maze of symlinks pointing to symlinks or targets that traverse symlinks to directories...